# There are 6 different logos on the 2.8 splash screen. What is the meaning of them?

Tags: interface, system

[image: These are on the 2.8 splash screen]

There are 6 different logos on the 2.8 splash screen. What is the meaning of them?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the icons for the different levels of donation subscriptions:
https://fund.blender.org/

Bronze, Silver, Gold, Platinum, Titanium, Diamond